# Is Blender the "right" program for modelling 3D puzzles?

Tags: modeling

My end goal is to make a 3D wooden "puzzle" model of a car for my nephew. The wooden car would be made up of Tetras-shaped blocks that can be dismantled and resembled assemble.

My plan is to import the drawings of my chosen car and 3D model it (should be straight forward. Next, I would split the model into different shaped blocks and then print these individual blocks out on paper to use as a template. I would then use these paper templates to make a working prototype out of foam.

As the only blender experience I have had is playing along with The Blender Guru's Donut tutorial, I would like to know if blender is the right program to do this? I have seen that you can brake models down into cubes in Blender but it doesn't seem to keep the overall shape.

Comment: Blender can make almost any shape you want. Does it require that you learn how to use it? Yes. There are some answers here that you might find useful. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92440/workflow-to-model-and-texture-a-jigsaw-puzzle? and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75733/how-can-i-uv-unwrap-a-mesh-based-on-its-3d-perspective-in-the-viewport? and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92622/how-do-you-texture-multiple-objects-with-a-single-image?

Comment: Awesome, thanks I'll have a look at the links. Yeah there is a fair bit of learning ahead  and possibly a new gpu .